# Graalvm js interprets java.util.Date in different way than it did by nashorn js

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, graalvm

We have migrated from jdk8 to jdk17, and had to use graalvm js instead of nashorn js.
We found, that graalvm js interprets java.util.Date as long not as a Date. Here are 2 examples.

Using jdk8 (nashorn):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            Date activationDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse("04/30/2008 00:00:00");
            parameters.put("aActivationDate", activationDate);
            
            
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            
            Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
            bindings.putAll(parameters);
            
            engine.eval("print(aActivationDate)", bindings);
        }
```

The result of this code is:
**Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 EDT 2008**

Using jdk17 with graalvm js.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        Date activationDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse("04/30/2008 00:00:00");
        parameters.put("aActivationDate", activationDate);
                
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        
        Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        bindings.put("polyglot.js.nashorn-compat", true);
        bindings.putAll(parameters);
        
        engine.eval("print(aActivationDate)", bindings);
    }
```

The result of this code is:
**1209528000000**

What should be done so, that graalvm interprets java.util.Date in the same way as nashorn js?
Thank you.